# .htaccess error while forecefully accessing subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the current code for example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Which makes you add forefully https://www OR https:// if you have already put www.

The problem with this code is that even if i call subdomains like ex.example.com

it adds https://www.ex.example.com

what i want is for subdomain to redirect like this => https://ex.example.com

Please can anyone provide me a valid code ?

Comment: Why is this tagged for PHP? This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Do you want this `example.com` to `https://www.example.com` and its subdomain to `http://that.subdomain.com`?

Comment: i want the subdomain like `https://that.example.com` instead of `http`

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav Check whether it is working fine or not?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work fine.

```
RewriteEngine On

#for normal domains like example.com or example.in to redirect to https://www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.(com|in)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

#for subdomain like test.example.com to redirect to https://test.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([\.\w\-]*)\.(com|in)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: its working for main domain, as per subdomain its only woking for mail.test.com not for demo.test.com, why so ?

Comment: it should be working for that as well let check it once again

Answer (score 0):

To force https for subdomains , put the following right after **RewriteEngine on** line :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^off#sub\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

This will redirect **http://sub.example.com** to **https://sub.example.com** . You have put this before your other HTTPS Redirect rule otherwise your rule will override this.